# Specflow with .NetCore (MSTest) asks for .feature.cs file while building

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, specflow

I'm trying to create specflow tests with .NetCore and MSTest. As mentioned by Specflow, it won't generate any .feature.cs file for Feature files. But when I try to build my application it displays error for .feature.cs file not found.
[image: Packages list]
[image]

Comment: SpecFlow 3 has not support for .NET Core 3. This comes with SpecFlow 3.1.
But this should not be the reason for your error.

Comment: Issue resolved when I upgraded to 3.1.32 -beta..Thanks Andreas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that SpecFlow doesn't support .NET Core 3. It is supported with SpecFlow 3.1.